# Sending large amount of data from ISR using queues in RTOS

Tags: c, queue, stm32, freertos, rtos

I am working on an STM32F401 MC for audio acquisition and I am trying to send the audio data(384 bytes exactly) from ISR to a task using queues. The frequency of the ISR is too high and hence I believe some data is dropped due to the queue being full. The audio recorded from running the code is noisy. Is there any easier way to send large amounts of data from an ISR to a task?

The RTOS used is FreeRTOS and the ISR is the DMA callback from the I2S mic peripheral.

Comment: FreeRTOS `xQueueSendFromISR()` "queues by copy", meaning it makes a copy of the data, which takes some time.  You should redesign so that the ISR does not spend time copying the data.  Maybe send by reference.

Comment: @kkrambo use memory pools and queue only the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a "zero copy" queue by creating a queue of pointers to memory blocks rather than copying the memory itself.  Have the audio data written directly to a block (by DMA for example), then when full, enqueue a pointer to the block, and switch to the next available block in the pool.  The receiving task can then operate directly on the memory block without needing to copy the data either into and out of the queue - the only thing copied is the pointer.

The receiving task when done, returns the block back to the pool.  The pool should have the same number of blocks as queue length.

To create a memory pool you would start with a static array:

```
tAudioSample block[QUEUE_LENGTH][BLOCK_SIZE] ;
```

Then fill a `block_pool` queue with pointers to each block element - pseudocode:

```
for( int i = 0; i < QUEUE_LENGTH; i++ )
{
    queue_send( block_pool, block[i] ) ;
}
```

Then to get an "available" block, you simply take a pointer from the queue, fill it, and then send to your audio stream queue, and the receiver when finished with the block posts the pointer back to the `block_pool`.

Some RTOS provide a fixed block allocator that does exactly what I described above with the `block_pool` queue.  If you are using the CMSIS RTOS API rather than native FreeRTOS API, that provides a [memory pool API](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTOS2/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__PoolMgmt.html).

However, it sounds like this may be an X-Y problem - you have presented your diagnosis, which may or may not be correct and decided on a solution which you are then asking for help with.  But what if it is the wrong or nor the optimum solution?  Better to include some code showing how the data is generated and consumed, and provide concrete information such as where this data is coming from, how often the ISR is generated, sample rates, the platform it is running on, the priority and scheduling of the receiving task, and what other tasks are running that might delay it.

On most platforms 384 bytes is not a large amount of data, and the interrupt rate would have to be extraordinarily high or the receiving task to be excessively delayed (i.e not real time) or doing excessive or non-deterministic work to cause this problem.  It may not be the ISR frequency that is the problem, but rather the performance and schedulability of the receiving task.

It is not clear if you 384 bytes results in a single interrupt or 384 interrupts or what?

That is to say that it may be a more holistic design issue rather than simply how to pass data more efficiently - though that can't be a bad thing.

Comment: I am receiving 384 bytes in a single interrupt. The problem with the audio acquisition is that due to this interrupt other interrupts such as I2C is slowing down considerably.

Comment: @Thilak :  If this interrupt preempts another and causes it to miss its deadlines, then either you have the interrupt priorities wrong or the interrupt is doing "too much" - or both.  The principles of RMS should be applied, and interrupts should do minimal work.    In my suggestion - DMA buffers that are from a fixed-block memory pool and a queue of pointers will reduce the work in thee ISR to _very little_.  Either way it sounds like an X-Y problem - you have scheduling issues, you think you have a solution, and you are asking about implementing it - ask about the actual problem instead.

Comment: RMS btw - Rate Monotonic Scheduling - the handler with the shortest run-time gets the highest preemption priority.  If that causes a missed deadline you have to optimise the handler so it runs for less time so can take a higher priority.

Comment: I read the question again and see that you are already using DMA, so you are half way there.  You just need to set the DMA buffer to a new memory block from the pool on each interrupt and pass the pointer on the queue - avoid a 384 byte memcpy.  Even then you may get away with the memcpy if you set the priorities correctly (and use preemption priorities).

Comment: You still have not specified the timing.  As an example, one project I have worked on with a 72MHz STM32F107 transfers 240 bytes from three ADC DMA buffers every 833 microseconds whist dealing with multiple UART, USB I2C and SPI streams.  In that case a queue was unnecessary, the DMA Half/Full transfer double buffering was sufficient.  It was not "zero-copy" the ADC samples form the three channels were "de-interleaved" into shared memory buffers.  So you can see why I am sceptical about your design, and why specification of the timing is essential to understanding your problem.

Comment: I am using STM's X-CUBE Audio library for Audio streaming through USB. For each DMA Half/Full interrupt 768 bytes of PDM data is converted to PCM Data and sent to buffer. It takes 1ms for each interrupt. This is running properly and I am able to stream audio. The problem is, this interrupt is slowing down other interrupts, especially an IMU sensor interrupt running at 400Hz sample rate. Yes you are right, I thought that I  found a solution instead of asking the problem. Can you help me in this regard?

Comment: I believe ST's USB stack runs entirely in the interrupt context (at least their earlier pre-CubeMX libraries did).  The execution time the USB ISR can be lengthy and highly variable (nor really suitable for and ISR at all).  The quick solution that will probably work is to use _only_ interrupt  preemption priorities and set the USB interrupt to the lowest priority (following rate-monotonic scheduling principles). The USB cannot then delay other interrupts and assuming _they_ are well behaved, they will have no significant impact on the USB. ...

Comment: ... An alternative is to move all the USB stack to an RTOS task and trigger it with a task event flag issued from the ISR.  The ISR will then be fast and deterministic (as all ISR's should be).  When I used USB on and STM32F1xx @72MHz I used that approach, for faster processors the simpler preemption priority assignment was sufficient, but only because the USB ISR run-time was no longer long enough for RTOS tasks to miss their deadlines.  In short this is a matter of appropriate priority assignment rather than moving data faster - short of re-writing the USB stack that is.

Comment: It is a mistake to think that making the USB ISR the highest priority will improve things or magically make it run faster - quite the opposite, it is what is delaying other interrupts.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling and in particular the section on ISRs.

Comment: ... The DMA interrupt too needs to be lower priority.

Answer (score 3):

The general approach in these cases is:

1. Down-sample the raw data received in the ISR (e.g., save only 1 out of 4 samples)
2. Accumulate a certain number of samples before sending them in a message to the task

Comment: This is a good suggestion, although it will depend on what is being done by the receiving thread.  For example, if the receiving thread is doing some sort of bulk processing, such as an FFT or some special type of filtering, it may not be possible.

Comment: @JonathonS: In my experience, any type of FS or Disk activity (recording, in this case), must take place in a separate thread. This is because this type of activity typically suffers sporadic lags due to FS data being rearranged from time to time. For example, saving a data-frame usually takes a few milliseconds, but every some time, it "suddenly" takes half a second. So in short, you would want to split that thread into two threads - one for processing and one for recording.

Comment: It may be correct.  I would definitely use the approach that you suggested if the objective is to down-sample the data before processing it in the receiving task.

Answer (score 1):

If the thread receiving the data is called at periodic intervals, the queue should be sized sufficiently to hold all data that may be received in that interval.  It would probably be a good idea to make sure the queue is large enough to hold data for at least two intervals.

If the thread receiving the data is simply unable to keep up with the incoming data, then one could consider increasing its priority.

There is some overhead processing associated with each push to and pull from the queue, since FreeRTOS will check to determine whether a higher priority task should wake up in response to the action.  When writing or reading multiple items to or from the queue at the same time, it may help to suspend the scheduler while the transfer is taking place.

Another solution would be to implement a circular buffer and place it into shared memory.  This will basically perform the same function as a queue, but without the extra overhead.  You may need to use a mutex to block simultaneous access to the buffer, depending on how the circular buffer is implemented.

Comment: I'd also consider to use the (leaner/faster) FreeRTOS streambuffer (or messagebuffer) mechanism and as mentioned give the post-processing task a reasonable high prio to avoid/minimize backlog.